# ¿Como cambiar el mensaje de alerta para inputs de formularios?

Tags: jquery, html5, entrada

¿Como le coloco un mensaje personalizado a las alertas de Firefox, Chrome y Edge cuando los Inputs tipo: text, number, tel, etc. No hayan sido rellenados o cuando tengan contenido erroneo? Por ejemplo:

Correo:
¿Vacio?

{ $Mensaje("Por favor coloca un Correo Valido para Contactar contigo.") }

Correo:

correo1234@URL (URL invalida sin ".com", que en este caso el navegador se conforma con tener solo una letra luego del "@")

{ $Mensaje("Por favor verifica el Correo.") }

Quiero modificar este mensaje "Rellene este campo":

[image: Foto de Mensaje de alerta en las etiquetas Inputs Erroneas]

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Aunque la pregunta es válida y pertinente al sitio, sería idea que incluyeras algo de código (lo que lleves y/o lo que hayas intentado). Lee [ask] y [mcve] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la bienvenida! La cuestion es que no coloque codigo porque realmente no sabia ni por donde empezar, pero luego de buscar y buscar todo el dia di con la solucion... muy sencilla en realidad, la encontre en StackOverflow en ingles. voy a postearla como respuesta! Muchas gracias de antemano :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se puede hacer definiendo tus propios mensajes de error con [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/HTML/HTML5/Validacion_de_restricciones#Restricciones_complejas_usando_la_API_de_Restricciones_de_HTML5).

Lo que harías sería leer el evento [`onInvalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/invalid) que se lanza cuando el campo es inválido (p.e. si es requerido pero se deja vacío, o si tiene un patrón que no se cumple), comprobar qué es lo que falló y mostrar un mensaje personalizado que definirías con `setCustomValidity`. También deberías añadir la lógica cuando se cambie el campo para quitar el mensaje si se solucionó el problema.

Aquí voy a dejar un ejemplo para un email: se comprueba que no esté vacío, que tenga una arroba (@) y que tenga un ".com" después de la @:

```js
function comprobarNombre(valor, campo) {
  
  var mensaje = "";
  
  // comprobar los posibles errores
  if (this.value == "") {
    mensaje = "El email no puede estar vacío";
  } else if (this.value.indexOf("@") < 0) {
    mensaje = "El email debe contener una @";
  } else if (this.value.indexOf(".com", this.value.indexOf("@")) < 0) {
    mensaje = "El email debe contener .com detras de la @";
  } 
  
  // mostrar/resetear mensaje (el mensaje se resetea poniendolo a "")
  this.setCustomValidity(mensaje);
}

var email = document.querySelector("#email");

// cuando se cambie el valor del campo o sea incorrecto, mostrar/resetear mensaje
email.addEventListener("invalid", comprobarNombre);
email.addEventListener("input", comprobarNombre);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo para tu campo de email, comprobando que contenga sólo una @, que el primer carácter no sea un ".", etc. (también podrías ponerle el tipo "email" al `input` que hará muchas de esas comprobaciones por ti).

Comment: Excelente amigo muchas gracias! Esto es lo que estaba buscando desde hace tantas horas! te agradesco, para lo del correo seria colocar la verificacion para el .com  como string? o me equivoco?

Comment: @JLAcostaE he actualizado la respuesta para que sea un email en lugar de un nombre y que compruebe que no esté vacío, que tenga una @ y que tenga un .com detrás de la @. Dime si así está mejor

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias Alvaro! Si ya entiendo todo, para los demas campos ya se que tengo que hacer, muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

La solucion a mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Usando este simple parametro dentro de la etiqueta Input se puede modificar el mensaje de alerta en el caso de haya error en el Input que seria:

> `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('El mensaje que se desea mostrar')"`

Para obtener el input siguiente:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor ingresa tu nombre')">
```

Y con eso obtuve el resultado que queria, sin embargo sigo en duda para verificar el campo de correo si no esta correcto... Sigo investigando y esperando que alguien pueda ayudarme porque realmente no se por donde empezar este codigo, soy nuevo en esto...